# Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I am facing this issue while integrating stripe payment in my app. I am using kotlin version 1.6.10 and also having minimum SDK version 21.

Error is showing that:

e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeAubecsDebitPlatformViewFactory.kt: (13, 1): Class 'StripeAubecsDebitPlatformViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeAubecsDebitPlatformViewFactory.kt: (19, 5): 'create' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkCardFormPlatformViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'StripeSdkCardFormPlatformViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkCardFormPlatformViewFactory.kt: (18, 5): 'create' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkCardPlatformViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'StripeSdkCardPlatformViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkCardPlatformViewFactory.kt: (18, 5): 'create' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkGooglePayButtonPlatformViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'StripeSdkGooglePayButtonPlatformViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\flutter\stripe\StripeSdkGooglePayButtonPlatformViewFactory.kt: (18, 5): 'create' overrides nothing

This is my build.gradle app-level file.

''' '''

Comment: It looks like you meant to add your `build.gradle` file, but it seems to have not made it.  Can you add that?  Also, can you run `flutter doctor` and edit your answer with the output of that?  Finally, does running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` help at all?

Comment: Getting same issue

Comment: did your issue got solved?

Answer (score 0):

For temporary solution you can fix it with this changes.[solution](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/pull/654/files)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `MainActivity` (inside `app/src/main/kotlin`) to this:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
class MainActivity(): FlutterFragmentActivity() {

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.